# Jquery Datatables select row that is on other page than 1st

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Hi I have a datatable which is included like this

```
$('.bt-datatable').DataTable(
      {
        info: false,
        paging: true,
        pageLength: 5,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
          { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
        ]
      }
  );
```

And this is my datatable Html it has the loop coded in ruby language which creates the multiple rows according to the user records

```
<div class="table-responsive"style="display: none">
          <hr>
          <table class="bt-datatable table table-striped click-row-datatable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left">Name</th>
              <th class="text-left">Status</th>
              <th class="text-left">Start Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <%
               @users.each do |user|

            %>
                <tr class='clickable-row' rel="<%= user.id %>">
                  <td class="text-left"><%= user.name %></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><%= user.status %></td>
                  <td class="text-left"><%= user.start_time %></td>

                </tr>
            <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

i have a flash variable in ruby which is saved in `flash[:user_id]`

what i am doing is somehow i get the flash[:user_id] saved and according to that i wanna highlight the row whose rel attribute is equal to flash[:user_id]

this is the javascript when the page loads

```
var ele = $('[rel="<%= flash[:user_id] %>"]');
    ele.addClass('bg-info');
```

the addClass is highlighting the the row in the datatable , but the issue i am facing is when the user id row is in lets say on the other page than 1st it does not loads the table on that page and not even highlighting, rather it only highlights when the that user is in the 1st page

Comment: You to store your database to make it available on other pages. `localStorage` is great for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Datatables has a [$()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) function that you can use to run a jQuery selector across the whole table, not just the visible rows. In your case, it would be something like:

```
var table = $('.bt-datatable').DataTable(
  {
    info: false,
    paging: true,
    pageLength: 5,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
    ]
  }
);

var ele = table.$('[rel="<%= flash[:user_id] %>"]');
ele.addClass('bg-info');
```

However, since it seems you already know which row to highlight at the time ruby renders it, wouldn't it be better to let ruby handle it? Something like (disclaimer: I'm not familiar with ruby):

```
<tr class='clickable-row <% if user.id == flash[:user_id] %> bg-info<% end %>'>
```

**Part II**

To show the page where the selected row is, you could use the [row().show()](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/row().show()) plugin. To do this you need to add the plugin script, and in your code, call `show()` on the row to show the correct page:

```
 var ele = table.$('.bg-info'); // TR element (assuming you used ruby to add the class)
 var row = table.row(ele); // Datatables row
 row.show().draw(false); // Show the page this row is in (and draw it)
```

Or shorter:

```
table.row('.bg-info').show().draw(false);
```

Comment: that works partially , as i am getting the user highlighted but that page of datatable doesnt come up selected,
 the issue is when there will be say thousands of users in the table and if the highlighted user is on the 20th page i want to preload that 20th page on the datatable

Comment: @user4965201 I think this is what you want. You should edit your question  to add this requirement